# Jenkins: conditionally start a project

Tags: jenkins, hudson, post-build

Jenkins builds the setup projects of our software suite. Afterwards, it starts a virtual machine with XP, installs our software, performs some tests, and shuts the VM down. Next, the same installation and test procedure shall be done on Win7, then on Win8, Server 2008 R2, Server 2012...

That means, when the "shutdown slave" project was done, a new slave has to be started depending on the previous slave.

The "Post build task" plugin allows for scripts to be executed dependent on the output of the project (I could add a "ver" statement there to get the relevant information), but it cannot start a project.

Another plugin allows for an action dependent on the outcome the project (success, instable, failure) - but that's not applicable here.

Currently, I think of creating specific batch files for each slave which would start the next client via vmrun and then shutdown the present slave. But I do not like that type of workaround, because the information on the order of projects get moved away from the Jenkins master.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [VMWare plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/VMware+plugin)?

Comment: Yes, I know the VMWare plugin. First, it does not work when the server is running on a 64bit machine (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17214). Next, it does not at all provide a possibility to start a specific machine after a task has been performed dependent on the machine where that task had been performed.
Let me repeat:
- After setups were built, start machine XP
- after installation and test were performed on XP, start machine Win7
- after the same (!) installation and test were performed on Win7, start Win 8
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like the slave jenkins instances are more trouble than they're worth in your case.

What about one big batch file that will run on the master and will control both the startup/shutdown of the virtual machines and the running of the install/test procedure on each of them?